# Creating a 3 columed banner which is dynamic when browser resizes and after a min-width it centers on the middle column

Tags: html, css, layout, dynamic, banner

Basicly if you look at http://drugraid.3owl.com you can see they have a banner and when you resize the webpage the middle column stays cenetered at all times while the side banners slowly creep in to the center. Here is the code i have so far. It would be great if someone helped me.

```
<!--HTML CODE-->
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Testing layouts</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">1 TEST</div>
    <div id="middle">2 TEST</div>
    <div id="right">3 TEST</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE

```
body {
margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
height: 35px;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-left: 2px;
padding-right: 2px;
min-width: 900px;
}

#left {
background-color: #ADA5A1;
height: 35px;
width: 16%;
float: left;
}

#middle {
background-color: #7D726D;
height: 35px;
width: 68%;
float: left;
}

#right {
background-color: #ADA5A1;
height: 35px;
width: 16%;
float: left;
}
```

ALSO if you have time u can try to make it work with... the margin of 2px so the boxes have spacing of 2px; next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try just one container centered

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/IdrGa

```
#maincontainer {
  min-height:100%;
  width:60%;
  min-width:600px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: well no that doesnt work because if u try it in a browser you get an issue because it shows the scroll bar at the bottom and.... the center column doesnt stop moving once it aligned in the center. Plus the white area on the left of the wrapper disappears.

Comment: scrollbar , hmm yes it's typical when content is bigger than window; for the middle container, do you mean you want it to be cropped as well ? because at one point its width comes bigger than window's width .Your exemple link is not 3 col but 1 container in the center, the sides are backgrounds

Comment: no my window size is 1300 px and can handle it fine but the bar for some reason is the same and if u keep shrinking the size then the middle area goes of the screen.... i kind of want a min-width working with it. I think

Comment: when i added min-width: 900px; to the middle div the pieces jumped all over the website when it was resized. go look at http://drugraid.3owl.com again and tell me how they managed it.

Comment: as i said, it is not 3 cols, but just one container centered. what you believe being coloumns is just the background-image repeating :)

Comment: change my answer for just one container.

Comment: that seems to work but there is glitches if u try it in browser. I jammed the website with 500 lines of text and if u scroll past your browser size you get another banner and another and another.

Comment: You need to add :   background-repeat:no-repeat; to html,body ;)

Comment: Try to run this in ie, The top bar wont appear unless u select compatability mode (older websites). Is there a way to solve this. Thanks

Comment: yes, for older IEs, use a background-image , a valid doctype (avoid transitionnal html or xhtml). test with real stand alone older IEs to trust your CSS test. .. do you have a link ?